# Johnson–Lindenstrauss lemma for lower dimension to higher dimension

Tags: vector-spaces, metric-spaces

In the very general sense, JL lemma states that "there exists a low distortion embedding from a higher dimensional metric space to a lower dimensional metric space".   Can I also use JL lemma to find an embedding from lower dimensional metric space to higher dimension ?  In the lemma, the bound on the embedding space dimension (lower dimensional in the description above) is a lower bound.  Hence, for any value higher than the bound is trivially true.

Does that mean that I can use JL lemma to embedd from lower dimension to higher dimension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to embed $\mathbb{R}^n$ into a higher dimensional space, you can just use the inclusion map. This is a linear map and will preserve the distances between points in $\mathbb{R}^n$. **Edit:** The inclusion map $\iota: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ where $m > n$ sends the standard basis $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $e_1, \ldots, e_n \in \mathbb{R}^m$. For example, if $n = 2$ and $m = 3$, the inclusion map sends $\mathbb{R}^2$ to the $xy$-plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$. You can check that $\iota$ preserves the distance between two points.

If you are referring to the variant of JL that deals with random projections, I believe it is also true if you embed into a higher dimensional space. However, this defeats the purpose of the JL lemma. The motivation is that in extremely high dimensions, it is hard to compute inter-point distances. The JL lemma says that you can project to a lower dimensional space and maintain the *relative* distance between the points. This makes algorithms such as $k$-nearest neighbors much more efficient.

Comment: I do not see any literature pointing to inclusion map. Can you please point me to some literature discussing inclusion map to embed a $k$ dimensional vector to $n$ dimensional vector where $k << n$.

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain the inclusion map. You can think of it as sending $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself viewed as a subspace of a higher dimensional space. Note that the inclusion map is used in many settings, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion_map gives a good definition of it. I hope this is clearer, let me know if it makes sense!